# No configuration setting found for key 'wdm.geckoDriverVersion' - WebDriverManager

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

I'm using the webdrivermanager(Java) and I think is configured (pom.xml), because Chrome and IE are working. Only FireFox is showing this menssage "No configuration setting found for key 'wdm.geckoDriverVersion'"

*The exemple works to.

So, Boni or other member can help me with this problem?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have this error only with PhantomJs and FireFox. The code is the same(examples git). First I thought that would be the POM but Chrome and IE are working. Thanks for your support.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJOnO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/at3qm.png

Comment: Which version of WebDriverManager are you using? Could you share some code snippets to try to find the problem?

Comment: WebDriverManager 1.5.0
I edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the library used by WebDriverManager for configuration ([com.typesafe.config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)) is not able to find the properties file for some reason. As of WebDriverManager 1.5.0, this file name is `webdrivermanager.properties`.

In any case, I would use the latest version of WebDriverManager and try again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it now. :)

Comment: Boni, now I have the webdrivermanager.properties. And I get another error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.getDriverVersion()Ljava/lang/String;"

Comment: Why do you need a custom webdrivermanager.properties? What is the content of that file?

Comment: I don´t need, the 1.5.0 version doesn´t have this file. I had other msg error "No configuration setting found for key 'wdm.geckoDriverVersion' - WebDriverManager" . Now I put the 1.6.0 and I have this file but another error appear " io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.getDriverVersion()Lj‌​ava/lang/String"

Only with PhantomJs and FireFox, I need to config something specific? I mean, POM. I followed the git Instruction.

Comment: I'm not sure. Some tips to try to solve this: 1. Do not override webdrivermanager.properties. 2. See working examples [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples). If the error is still there, you need to provide the full forensic information about your project/problem (call to FirefoxDriverManager, complete trace log, complete pom.xml)

Comment: Ok, Boni. I'll try it.